# Assigning axios response whilst iterating through array of objects

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm looking to assign a value to an array of objects inside a Axios call. I can't figure out how to assign the values to the new array. Below is the code I have so far.

Thank you.

```
app.get('/matchedusers', (req, res) => {
  plexClient.getAllUsers().then(plexUsers => {
    axios.get('https://tautulli.link/api/v2?apikey=API-KEY&cmd=get_users_table&length=150')
      .then((tautulliUser) => {
        let tautulliUsers = tautulliUser.data.response.data.data
        let matchedUsers = []
        let timedUsers = []
        

        // Doing a check to see if tautulli user is also a plex user.
        tautulliUsers.forEach((tautulliUser) => {
          plexUsers.forEach((plexUser) => {
            if(tautulliUser.username == plexUser.username || tautulliUser.username == plexUser.email){
              matchedUsers.push({id: plexUser.id, username: plexUser.username, email: plexUser.email})
            }
          })
        })


        matchedUsers.forEach((user) => {
          axios.get(`https://tautulli.link/api/v2?apikey=API-KEY&cmd=get_user_watch_time_stats&user_id=${user.user_id}&query_days=7`)
            .then((watchTime) => {
              // I want to add the matched user to timedUsers and add the watchTime response. Something like "timedUsers.push({...user, response: response})"
              // This is the part that I can't figure out.
            })
        })


        
        // Use the timedUsers array to display the results.
        console.log(timedUsers)
        res.json(timedUsers)
      })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Promise.all(arrayOfPromises).then(...)` to wait for an array of promises to finish.

If you ever introduce async code in a Javascript function, you always need to wait for the async response to finish, so you can only access the array inside the next `.then()`.

Changing the entire function to use the `async`/`await` syntax can make this a little nicer to work with.

```
Promise.all(matchedUsers.map((user) =>
  axios.get(`https://tautulli.link/api/v2?apikey=API-KEY&cmd=get_user_watch_time_stats&user_id=${user.user_id}&query_days=7`)
    .then((response) => ({ ...user, response }))
).then(res => {
  timedUsers = res;
}
```

Note the `matchedUsers.map((user) => axios.get...` syntax, which doesn't put a curly brace around the function body. This is an implicit Javascript return, so the map will **return** an array of the axios get promises.

Same for `(response) => ({ ...user, response })`, which is an explicit return of an object from a function. You must wrap the object in `(` `)` to signify it's an implicit object return.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Promise.all`, also I converted your route to async/await syntax as it is much easier to read and work with. It is not recommended to await in the loop it is better to push all the promises to an array and then use `Promise.all` to wait for the all.

```js
app.get('/matchedusers', async(req, res) => {

  const allUsers = await plexClient.getAllUsers();

  const tautulliUser = await axios.get('https://tautulli.link/api/v2?apikey=API-KEY&cmd=get_users_table&length=150');

  let tautulliUsers = tautulliUser.data.response.data.data
  let matchedUsers = []
  let timedUsers = []

  tautulliUsers.forEach((tautulliUser) => {
    plexUsers.forEach((plexUser) => {
      if (tautulliUser.username == plexUser.username || tautulliUser.username == plexUser.email) {
        matchedUsers.push({
          id: plexUser.id,
          username: plexUser.username,
          email: plexUser.email
        })
      }
    })
  })

  matchedUsers.forEach((user) => {
    const response = axios.get(`https://tautulli.link/api/v2?apikey=API-KEY&cmd=get_user_watch_time_stats&user_id=${user.user_id}&query_days=7`);
    timedUsers.push({ ...user,
      response
    });
  })
  const final = await Promise.all(timedUsers);

  console.log(final)
  res.json(final)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `async/await` syntax, and use `Promise.all` and `map` to resolve the request promises first then add them to `timedUsers` array.

```js
app.get("/matchedusers", async (req, res) => {
    const plexUsers = await plexClient.getAllUsers();
    const tautulliUser = await axios.get(
        "https://tautulli.link/api/v2?apikey=API-KEY&cmd=get_users_table&length=150"
    );
    let tautulliUsers = tautulliUser.data.response.data.data;
    let matchedUsers = [];
    let timedUsers = [];

    // Doing a check to see if tautulli user is also a plex user.
    tautulliUsers.forEach((tautulliUser) => {
        plexUsers.forEach((plexUser) => {
            if (
                tautulliUser.username == plexUser.username ||
                tautulliUser.username == plexUser.email
            ) {
                matchedUsers.push({
                    id: plexUser.id,
                    username: plexUser.username,
                    email: plexUser.email,
                });
            }
        });
    });

    // I want to add the matched user to timedUsers and add the watchTime response. Something like "timedUsers.push({...user, response: response})"
    // This is the part that I can't figure out.

    timedUsers = await Promise.all(
        matchedUsers.map(async (user) => {
            const response = await axios.get(
                `https://tautulli.link/api/v2?apikey=API-KEY&cmd=get_user_watch_time_stats&user_id=${user.user_id}&query_days=7`
            );
            return { ...user, response }
        })
    );


    // Use the timedUsers array to display the results.
    console.log(timedUsers);
    res.json(timedUsers);
});
```